# How to convert binary XML data from Postgresql field to C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database, where one of my columns is binary data with a compressed XML file.

In C#, how can I convert this data to an XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the manual for details regarding this:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING

Ex.

```
SELECT xpath('//fw:MyPassword/text()', CAST(convert_from(bytea_column, 'UTF-8') AS XML))FROM your_table;
```

or

```
string myXml = XDocument.Load("G:\\new repo\\setting xmls\\settings.xml").ToString()
```

then

```
string sql0 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Public.""UserProfile"" (setting, userstatus, userstatusdescription, id) VALUES ('{0}', true, 'active', 'ddd');", myXml);
```